# Use custom tables in diagrams

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to insert a standard table, with columns and rows, into a diagram? I haven't been able to find it in any toolset.

Comment: What kind of columns/rows?

Comment: @ThomasKilian basically a table you'd create in MS Word for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not really possible. There are 3 ways to mimic a table.

1. **Boundary** Using a boundary lets you create a matrix shape.

   [image]

   Values inside need to be placed manually from single text elements.
2. **Diagram** A diagram can take a matrix from the context `Swimlanes and Matrix...`

   [image]

   Again, text has to be placed manually.

   Since the whole diagram appears as matrix you need to use diagram frames which appear with a diagram boundary:

   [image]

   The frame can finally be hidden:

   [image]
3. **Ultima ratio** The most simple way: Take a screen shot from Excel and place the image in the diagram.

Comment: I remembered how to hide the frame for diagrams. See my edit.